# how can i disable closing of jquery mobile popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i like to use jquery mobile to build a web application.
when i use 'jquery mobile signin popup' in here:
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-rc.1/docs/demos/widgets/popup/

and i like to customize signin popup as preloaded and user can unable to close it. just like static form in HTML. because without popup or disappered popup, user's cant signin and cant use services. how can i do that??

thank you for your time here is signup popup's source.

```
<a href="#popupLogin" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-icon="check" data-theme="a" data-transition="pop">Sign in</a>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
    <form>
        <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
            <h3>Please sign in</h3>
            <label for="un" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Username:</label>
            <input type="text" name="user" id="un" value="" placeholder="username" data-theme="a">
            <label for="pw" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Password:</label>
            <input type="password" name="pass" id="pw" value="" placeholder="password" data-theme="a">
            <button type="submit" data-theme="b" data-icon="check">Sign in</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Why popup at all, why not take them to a login page?

Comment: because i like the form ui of popup.. is there other way to use popup as a main ui?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `dismissible` attribute.

> Sets whether clicking outside the popup or pressing Escape while the
>   popup is open will close the popup. This option is also exposed as a
>   data attribute: data-dismissible="false"

Code:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupLogin" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all" data-dismissible="false">
```

Docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/pages/popup/options.html#

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7yqkd/

Answer (score 2):

Just add

```
data-dismissible="false"
```

to the popup

Comment: at least place the documentation where is the specifications of said property